# Python can't find class attribute

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I've hit a block when making a pygame project. the `display.py` file cant find the `render()` attribute in the `player.py` file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ethan\Desktop\pyprojects\pygame\display.py", line 34, in <module>
    player.render(screen)
AttributeError: Player instance has no attribute 'render'
```

I tried removing the reference to rendering the player. and it worked, plus the screen rendered properly. when I put the reference back in, the screen didn't render properly, and crashed all together

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me.

here's the code:

Windows 10
Python-2.7
pygame-1.9.3

**display.py**

```
import pygame
from player import *
import sys

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
white = (255,255,255)

screen_x = 800
screen_y = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_x, screen_y])
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = Player(0,0)

gameLoop = True

while gameLoop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameLoop = False

        print(event)

    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
    player.render(screen)
    screen.fill(white)


pygame.quit()
```

**player.py**

```
import pygame
from display import *
import sys

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32
    def render(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,0,255), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
```

again thanks!

Comment: you shoud rather do `screen.fill()` before `player.render()`

Answer (score 1):

I get a different error:

> ```
>     player = Player(0,0)
> NameError: name 'Player' is not defined
> ```

That happens because you import from `display` in the player.py file and that runs the display.py file before the `Player` is defined in player.py.

You could put the code inside display.py into a `main` function and call it in a special if clause:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That makes sure that the `main` function doesn't run when the display module gets imported.

Or you could remove the line `from display import *` in the player module. If there are things that both the player and display modules need, put them into another separate module.